# PHP function to shorten file directory strings

Tags: php, sql, web-applications

I am trying to store image file names to a SQL database. The file name looks something like "**_p4_analyzed__07001447_20121003-4000096925_Class2_reg_EPI.png**" and I was hoping that it would be just "**Class2_reg_EPI.png**".

I was hoping that this line will do the trick: `$fileName = str_ireplace($casePath."/","", $file)` but unfortunately when I run it it is still giving me the long name with the path (the '_' underscore acts as the '/'?)

See code below for more information:

```
$casePath=$path."/".$caseID."/Summary/slicesdir";
    global $status;
//    print("processImages case path:".$casePath."</br>");
     $files = glob($casePath."/*.png");

    $connection = getMySqlConnection();
    $imageCount= 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++) {
        $file = $files[$i];
        $fileName = str_ireplace($casePath."/","", $file);

        if(strripos($fileName, "grot") === false)
        {
            $imageCount ++;
            //if exists
            if(!doesImageExist($fileName, $patientID, $caseID)) {
                $id = uniqid("", true);
                 $sql = "Insert Into images(id,patientid,caseid, image_name,comments,status) VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($id)
                    ."','".mysql_real_escape_string($patientID)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($caseID)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($fileName)."',NULL,".$status[0][0].")";
//                 print($sql."</br>");
                 mysql_query("START TRANSACTION", $connection);
                $result = mysql_query($sql, $connection);
                if($result) {
                    mysql_query("COMMIT", $connection);
//                    print("Image data inserted </br>");
                 } else {
                    mysql_query("ROLLBACK", $connection);
                     print("Image Data failed </br>");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: @alchuang . . . Why is this tagged SQL?

Comment: You have to choose/define a pattern, what you expect and the desired output. That way you can use regex to rename your files.

Comment: If you put a different name in the database than the actual file name, how will you access the file later?

Comment: What do you mean by "the underscore acts as the /"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the original filename contains path information (e.g. `/path/to/the/file.png`), and you only want the filename (`file.png`), you can remove the path using [`basename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)

```
$filename = basename('/path/to/file.png');

echo $filename; // outputs 'file.png'
```

Comment: How does that get rid of `_p4_analyzed__07001447_20121003-4000096925` prefix? That's not directory information.

Comment: @Bamar based on the OP's attempt to replace the 'directory' / 'path' in the filename, it seems like he was attempting to remove the path (he mentions *"the '_' underscore acts as the '/'"*). I may be completely in the wrong direction with my answer, just added it in case he was looking for the obvious